# Speed of particle (on canvas) increases everytime I generate a new one. Is it due to requestanimationframe?

Tags: javascript, canvas

The aim is to use the class particle to create particles (upon the user clicking a button) and once that is running as it should be, to give the user some control over speed, gravity and some other things. The problem is that every time the user clicks to create a new particle, the speed increases.

I'm not sure why but when I demo it without having the requestanimationframe, it looks like it works as it should, but it's useless if it's not animated.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

const gravitySlider = document.getElementById('gravity-slider')
const output = document.getElementById('value')


//GENERIC PARTICLE CREATION

class particle{
    
    constructor(positionX, positionY, velocityX, velocityY, radius, color,){
    this.positionX = Math.max(radius, Math.min(1024 - radius, positionX))
    this.positionY = Math.min(768 - radius, positionY)
    this.velocityX = velocityX
    this.velocityY = velocityY
    this.radius = radius
    this.color = color
    }
    
update() {
    
    if (
      this.positionX > 1024 - this.radius || this.positionX < this.radius
    ) {
      this.velocityX *= -1
    }

    if (this.positionY >= 768 - this.radius || this.positionY < this.radius) {
      this.velocityY *= -1
    }

    this.velocityX *= 0.999
    this.velocityY += 1
    
    this.positionX += this.velocityX;
    this.positionY += this.velocityY;
    
    this.positionY = Math.min(768 - this.radius, this.positionY)
  }
    
    drawParticle() {
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.positionX, this.positionY, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fill();
  }
}

//CREATE BUTTON INTERACTIVITY AND CLICK COUNTING VARIABLE

const newParticleButton = document.getElementById('new-particle-button')
newParticleButton.onclick = drawNewParticle

//Even listener for click counting

let clickCount = 0
 
const clickCounter = document.querySelector('#new-particle-button')
clickCounter.addEventListener('click' ,function(event){
    clickCount+= 1 })

const particleArray = []

//DRAW NEW PARTICLES ON BUTTON PRESS

function drawNewParticle(){

    //Generate particle and add to array of particles

    generateParticle = particleArray.push (new particle(
    Math.random() * 1014,
    Math.random() * 758,
    1,
    1,
    10,
    'hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 1)'
    )
    )

    // clear canvas
    
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1024, 768)
    
    
    for(i=0; i< clickCount; i++){
    particleArray[i].update()
    particleArray[i].drawParticle()
    
    }
    
        requestAnimationFrame(drawNewParticle)
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Canvas Basics</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/index.css">
    <script src="scripts/canvas.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    
     <canvas id="canvas" width="1024" height="768" style="border: 1px dashed">
      Canvas is not supported
    </canvas>
      
     <button class="new-particle-button" id="new-particle-button">NEW PARTICLE</button>
     <div class="slidecontainer">
        <label for="gravity-slider">GRAVITY</label>
        <input type="range" min="0" max="10" value="0" class="slider" id="gravity-slider">
         <p>Value: <span id="value"></span></p>
     </div>
      
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to want to separate out your animation loop from your add particle function. All you need to do in the animate function is clear the canvas and update and draw objects. Adding to the array should be a separate function. Every time you click the button you are calling `requestAnimationFrame` again thus compiling its effect.

```
function drawNewParticle(){
    //Generate particle and add to array of particles
    generateParticle = particleArray.push (new particle(
    Math.random() * 1014,
    Math.random() * 758,
    1,
    1,
    10,
    'hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 1)'
    )
    )
}    

function animate() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1024, 768)
       
    for(i=0; i< clickCount; i++){
    particleArray[i].update()
    particleArray[i].drawParticle() 
    }   
    requestAnimationFrame(animate)
}
animate();
```

Comment: Cheers mate. Absolute legend

Answer (score 0):

I would check and see if its the fact that you are constantly running `drawNewParticle` as your animation function, I would put this (your particle creation function):

```js
particleArray.push (new particle(
    Math.random() * 1014,
    Math.random() * 758,
    1,
    1,
    10,
    'hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 1)'
    )
    );
```

under your event listener for the button, since it seems like you're creating an array of the particles on the screen, which gets a new item every frame.

I'm sorry if this doesn't help, maybe I just didn't understand your code correctly :\

Comment: Cheers. Was heading in the right direction

Comment: @Ahmed Yeah I fail to explain things when I get exited lol

Comment: It's alright man thanks for taking the time